# add class when child has class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that adds the class "selected-role" to the active tab and I am trying to change the border color of the parent when the form tab has the class "selected-role". How do I have it add it to only the "active" tab? right now it's adding the border color to all three tabs

```
<div class="register_checkbox_label-container col">
    <label tabindex="0" for="register_checkbox_one" class="form_checkbox_label form_checkbox_label--role selected-role" id="default-role" data-role="one">
        One
    </label>
</div>

<div class="register_checkbox_label-container col">
    <label tabindex="0" for="register_checkbox_two" class="form_checkbox_label form_checkbox_label--role" data-role="two"  data-offset="0">
        Two
    </label>
</div>

<div class="register_checkbox_label-container col">
    <label tabindex="0" for="register_checkbox_three" class="form_checkbox_label form_checkbox_label--role" data-role="three"  data-offset="0">
        Three
    </label>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
if($('.form_checkbox_label').hasClass('selected-role')){
      $(this).find('.register_checkbox_label-container').addClass('border-fuschia');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to achieve this. Simply select the parent element using the `:has()` selector to only match those with the given child element:

```js
$('.register_checkbox_label-container:has(.selected-role)').addClass('border-fuschia');
```

```css
.border-fuschia {
  border: 1px solid fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="register_checkbox_label-container col">
  <label class="selected-role">One</label>
</div>
<div class="register_checkbox_label-container col">
  <label>Two</label>
</div>
<div class="register_checkbox_label-container col">
  <label>Three</label>
</div>
```

Note that I only removed the non-essential parts of the HTML above to make the example shorter.